# Was A Song of Ice and Fire inspired by Chinese History, and if yes, to what extent?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I have noticed a few striking parallels between China's history and George R. R. Martin's epic fantasy, "A Song of Ice and Fire" series:

1. The Ice Wall resembles the Great Wall of China. Both are meant to keep out the "outsiders"
2. The Chinese tended to view themselves as the center of the world, and view the others as uncivilized and barbarians. In the same way the people from the Seven Kingdoms in the series view everything outside the Wall as "the Others".
3. Seven Kingdoms fighting among one another for the Iron Throne, this closely resembles the Seven Kingdom in China during [Spring and Autumn period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period).
4. Dragonstone. In the series, "[We learn that the Targaryens once ruled all of Westeros until a rebellion, punctuated by a few hideous slaughters, chased them to a small, craggy isle off the coast called Dragonstone](http://www.bustle.com/articles/23255-china-heavily-censored-game-of-thrones-this-might-be-why)" This description reminds me of [Kuomingtang's retreat to Taiwan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Kuomintang#1945.E2.80.9349) in 1949.

My question is, to what extent A Song of Ice and Fire was (and is) inspired by Chinese History?

Comment: What else is a wall for?

Comment: @Gusdor- Well, I suppose it could always be to keep the "insiders" in. The Berlin Wall, for example, was more about keeping East Germans from escaping.

Comment: I thought the point of the Great Wall was not just to keep outsiders out (a daunting challenge considering the number of people it would take to fully man it), but to simply delay invaders, both in their entry, and in their escaping with living and non-living loot.

Comment: A minor point: not all people beyond the Wall are Others. The Others are a race distinct from humans, but there are also humans living beyond the Wall and they are called wildlings, not Others.

Comment: @TenthJustice While that is of course the truth, the East German government still insisted that it had been built to keep the Imperialists _out_!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. The idea of the Wall was inspired [Hadrian's Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian%27s_Wall), but resembles a lot the Great Wall of China.
2. I think a lot of ancient civilizations believed that they were the center of the world. For instance, this also happened in ancient Greece. They thought that everyone else was a barbarian. The word 'barbarian' comes from the Greek word 'Βάρβαρος' (pronounced 'varvaros') ; people couldn't understand what others were saying, and every word sounded like 'βαρ βαρ' (pronc: 'var var'), thus βάρβαρος.
3. George Martin was inspired for his novels by the [War of the Roses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wars_of_the_Roses) as well as by the Hundred Years' War, the Crusades and the Albigensian Crusade. (["Interview: George Martin".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire#Writing_process) Deep Magic 41: 19–21. 2005.)

I don't know anything about the 4th point you mention

So, my conclusion would be that **no, A song of ice and fire has not been inspired by the Chinese History**. Most of Martin's influences are from European history, but I don't believe that that restricted him not to influence from other histories around the globe. So far though, that's all we have been told.

Comment: Additionally Essos bears many resemblances to Eurasia. The very eastern point of Essos ends at the Jade sea. This is quite an obvious reference to the Orient (think the Jade Empire). Little is known about this region, which reflects how little of East Asia was known to Medieval Europe.

Comment: 4. I always assumed that Ageons conquest was inspired by the first Norman King of England, William the Conqueror, I mean they share the same title and everything. Though I find these historical parallels amazing

Comment: I'm not a fan of the fourth point. Dragonstone was the last stronghold of a weakened dynasty for roughly a year. For the previous 300 or so, it was the proud, historical stronghold of a powerful dynasty, and before that the base of operations for a conqueror.

Comment: I've never understood how Hadrian's Wall was supposed to keep anyone out. You can vault over it, trivially; certainly a horse would have no trouble. You may struggle a little more with [heavily packed] carts, granted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A brief skim of wikipedia suggests it was 11-20ft (3.5-6m) high.  I certainly can't jump that high.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh, it's "shrunk" today (I've been there). Okay then

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: More to the point, Hadrian's Wall, like the Great Wall of China, was manned by guards. Once the Romans' numbers dwindled it became trivial to cross the wall just as it was with the Great Wall of China. Stones don't keep people out - they just make the border easier to defend.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes, it has shrunk. As with many Roman ruins all over Europe it was "mined" as a source of stone for building. At least some of what's there now is reconstructed (and not necessarily to full original size).

Comment: @SteveJessop: Even the analogy holds in that case; the Wall is scalable, even if not trivially, so it takes fortifications such as Castle Black to effectively maintain the integrity of the border.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, it certainly seems Mance believes Castle Black to be the only place his army can cross the Wall, albeit with a certain death rate you can send lightly-equipped raiders over in other places. Basically the watch is just manning the castles, most of the Wall is more or less abandoned but is big enough to stop an army anyway. By contrast, Hadrian's wall if not manned would (I suspect) have been vulnerable to just tearing a section down and crossing with carts, mammoths and all. The Wall is a better barrier than real-life border fortifications.

Comment: @Steve: Oh, I think that's clear. Just look at the size of that thing! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't have a reference for the interview, but a friend of mine claims that Martin initially objected to the TV show FX of the wall, claiming they'd made it too big. They said (words to the effect of), "it says in the book it's X feet, we made it X feet", and he said (words to the effect of) "wow, I didn't realise X feet was that much" ;-)

Answer (score 7):

In regard to your first point, [according to this recent interview](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/aug/16/george-rr-martin-game-of-thrones-interview) the Wall was not inspired by the Great Wall of China, although readers can certainly infer their own meanings:

> ... it seems to me that one reason for the huge success of both the book and TV versions is that people of different races and places detect their own experience in Martin's alternative world. Depending on your perspective, the great dividing barrier in the books could be Hadrian's Wall, the Great Wall of China or the security fence on the West Bank.
>
> **GRRM:** "Well, I can settle that one easily. It was Hadrian's Wall. I've never been to China."
>
> "But the point I'm making is that readers may see their own meanings?"
>
> **GRRM:** "Oh, sure. And those meanings may very well be there. An author is not necessarily infallible when discussing his own work because so much takes place in the subconscious."

Answer (score 3):

[Shevliaskovic answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66005/1166) all the points well. Unless Martin literally spells it out for us, it's hard to know what inspired him. I got the impression the Valyrian were inspired by the Romans. They ruled their world in every direction, had superior technologies (Valyrian steel / Byzantine Fire) but declined very suddenly.

It's not so much a case of China/England/Rome inspired the "A Song of Ice and Fire world" but more all the countries of this world inspired that world.

Comment: GRRM has spelled it out. ASOIAF was inspired by The War of the Roses and Hadrian's Wall.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant was unless he spells out any more inspirations it's just pure guesswork. I think I read somewhere he doesn't like people saying Dothraki = Mongol Horde. Is the Colossus of Bravos inspired by the Colossus of Rhodes, or some statue he came across in his Travels...

Comment: @MikeyMouse The Bravos=?Rhodes thing sounds a bit like a question waiting to be asked....

Answer (score -1):

I know there are already answers including an accepted one. However, I still would like to point out a similarity from JRR's The Silmarillion.

There is clear writing about the wall and the watch too. This is around 27% in the book.

> ...and they raised up the mountain-walls of the Pelóri to sheer and dreadful heights, east, north, and south. Their outer sides were dark and smooth, without foothold or ledge, and they fell in great precipices with faces hard as glass, and rose up to towers with crowns of white ice. A sleepless watch was set upon them, and no pass led through them, save only at the Calacirya...